# Change toggle button text color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am using [this](https://github.com/pellucide/Android-Switch-Demo-pre-4.0/tree/master/) library for creating switch toggle button.

I am wondering how could I change the text color which stayed behind. For more clear there is green switcher, the text is white, how could I change gray text which is not selectable. I couldn't find how to do this.

here is the style of mySwitch

```
 <style name="mySwitchStyle">
        <item name="switchTextAppearanceAttrib">@style/mySwitchTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="pushStyle">false</item>
        <item name="textOnThumb">true</item>
        <item name="thumbExtraMovement">0dp</item>
        <item name="thumbTextPadding">6dp</item>
        <item name="trackTextPadding">6dp</item>
        <item name="switchMinWidth">300dp</item>
        <item name="switchMinHeight">36dp</item>
        <item name="switchPadding">6dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="mySwitchTextAppearance">
        <item name="textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="textSize">28sp</item>
        <item name="textStyle">normal</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function setTextColor(int), [Documentation Link here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor%28int%29)